# How do I remove repeated values on grouping with Pandas and Matplotlib

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

Fairly new to using Pandas and Matplotlib. I have a data frame like below and I'd like to get a count of the users per application.

```
application    environment     user
   A                1           Bob
   A                2           Carol
   A                3           Bob
   B                2           Steve
   B                4           Mike
   C                1           Bob
   C                2           Bob
```

Using groupby on 'application' and 'user' I created a new column called count with the correct totals and removed 'environment'.  As an example:

```
application         user       Count
   A                Bob          2
   A                Carol        1
   A                Steve        3
   B                Carol        1
   B                Steve        5
   C                Steve        4
   C                Bob          2
```

I'd like to display the matplotlib table like below so the `application` isn't repeated.

```
application         user       Count
   A                Bob          2
                    Carol        1
                    Steve        3
   B                Carol        1
                    Steve        5
   C                Steve        4
                    Bob          2
```

I've looked through the Matplotlib documentation and google searched but can't find anything related.  I'm not sure if this needs to be handled at the data frame or when creating the Matplotlib table.

I'd appreciate any advice on how to create this final table.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I could've sworn I had asked a question like this before, but I can't find the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and then remove duplicate values by [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) + [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['application','user']).size().reset_index(name='count')
df['application'] = df['application'].mask(df['application'].duplicated() ,'')
print (df)
  application   user  count
0           A    Bob      2
1              Carol      1
2           B   Mike      1
3              Steve      1
4           C    Bob      2
```

And last create [table](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/table_demo.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Hide axes
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False) 
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)

ax.table(cellText=df.values, colLabels=df.columns, loc='center')
plt.show()
```

[image: table]

Comment: This worked thank you.  I was missing the mask + duplicated line.